# Define new Icon Collapsable JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to define custom icons for the JQuery Collapsable view. I would like to do this without having to modify the default JQuery CSS and .JS files.

Here is a jsFiddle of what I am starting with: http://jsfiddle.net/jakechasan/M7LLU/

I have tried this, but with no success:

```
#plus .ui-icon {
     background:  url(open.png) 50% 50% no-repeat; background-size: 24px 22px;
}
```

Here is my desired appearance: (notice a custom icon next to the row title) [Note: this is only a Photoshop mockup]

[image]

Does anyone have ideas on how to change this?

Thanks.

Comment: That's not really an icon that is available, you can find the available icons and how to change them here -> http://api.jquerymobile.com/icons/. For custom icons, maybe Font Awesome or similar projects would work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, I am trying to use an icon that is not standard, one from the Glyphish icon set. Any ideas on how to change the icon to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector for the icon set by jQuery Mobile seem to be `.ui-icon-plus:after`.

If you add that to your own CSS you could override the standard icon. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/M7LLU/7/)**

```
.ui-icon-plus:after {
    background: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/34/Red_star.svg") top center no-repeat;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting. I noticed that in this demo, the gray circle was still outlined around the star. Is there any way to remove that?

Comment: @JakeChasan Yes, you just need to add a CSS rule that overrides the background-color. I have updated my answer to override the background, instead of just background-image.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is close to what I am trying to do, but is there a way to reduce the radius of the circle that is bounding the image?

Comment: @JakeChasan just add border-radius: 0; together with background